# JavaScript - Div Elements Appending Twice on One Click

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousemove, mousedown

```js
//Global variables
let count = 1;
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');
let designBtn = document.querySelector('#design-btn');
let editBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-btn');
let isDesign = false;
let isEdit = false;
let circleArray = [];
let offset = [];


//Click event listener for design button
designBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  isDesign = true;
  isEdit = false;

  designBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#BA4A00'
  designBtn.style.color = '#17202A'

  editBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
  editBtn.style.color = null

  //Invoke being_design function
  begin_design()
})

//Click event listener for edit button
editBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  isDesign = false;
  isEdit = true;

  editBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#BA4A00'
  editBtn.style.color = '#17202A'

  designBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
  designBtn.style.color = null

  //Invoke edit_design function
  edit_design()
})



//Function creates new element and then appends it to the parent div
function create_circle_element(x, y){
  let circle = document.createElement('div')

  const circleHeight = 40;
  const circleWidth = 40;

  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  circle.style.height = `${circleHeight}px`;
  circle.style.width = `${circleWidth}px`;
  circle.style.borderRadius = '50%'
  circle.style.textAlign = 'center';
  circle.style.lineHeight = `${circleHeight}px`;
  circle.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  circle.style.left = `${(x - (canvas.offsetLeft + canvasContainer.offsetLeft - window.scrollX)) - (circleWidth/2)}px`;
  circle.style.top = `${(y -(canvas.offsetTop + canvasContainer.offsetTop - window.scrollY)) - (circleHeight/2)}px`

  circle.textContent = `${count}`;
  canvas.append(circle)
  circleArray.push(circle)
  count++
}


//Function responsible for adding circles to the canvas
//Function is invoked when design button is clicked
function begin_design(){
    let mousePosition;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{
    if(isDesign){
      mousePosition = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      }
        create_circle_element(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
      }
    })
}


//Function responsible for editing the circles on the canvas i.e moving them around on mousedown/mousemove event
//Function is invoked when edit button is clicked
function edit_design(){
  if(isEdit){
  let mouseDown = false;
  let offset = [];
  let circleClickedOn = [];

//Set mouseDown to false
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
    mouseDown = false
  })

//Loop through the newly created circles and attached 'mousedown' event to each
  circleArray.forEach((circleElement)=>{
    circleElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{

      mouseDown = true;
      offset = [
        circleElement.offsetLeft - event.clientX,
        circleElement.offsetTop - event.clientY
      ]
      circleClickedOn = [circleElement]
    })
  })

//Move circles around
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
    if(mouseDown){
     let mousePosition;

     mousePosition = {
       x: event.clientX,
       y: event.clientY
     }

     circleClickedOn[0].style.left = `${offset[0] + mousePosition.x}px`
     circleClickedOn[0].style.top = `${offset[1] + mousePosition.y}px`
    }
  })
}
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #17202A;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-top{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-top #toggle-btn{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #808B96
}

.sidebar .sidebar-center{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #808B96
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #2e4053
}


.canvas-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2E4053
}

.canvas-container #canvas{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-top">
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="toggle-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-center">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="design-btn">
                <i class='bx bx-pyramid'></i>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" id="edit-btn">
                <i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <div id="canvas"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Objective** - When user clicks design button, the circles are added to the canvas on `mousedown` event. When user clicks the edit button, they are able to move the circles around. When the design button is clicked again, user is able to continue adding circles and incrementing the number from where it was left off.

**Error to resolve** - When design is first clicked, I am able to successfully add circles to the canvas. If I click on edit button and move the circles around and then click on design button right after, it appends two circles on on click. Why is it appending two circles? This only happens after I click on edit.

```
***JAVASCRIPT***
//Global variables
let count = 1;
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container')
let designBtn = document.querySelector('#design-btn');
let editBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-btn');
let isDesign = false;
let isEdit = false;
let circleArray = [];
let offset = []


//Click event listener for design button
designBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  isDesign = true;
  isEdit = false;

  designBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#BA4A00'
  designBtn.style.color = '#17202A'

  editBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
  editBtn.style.color = null

  //Invoke being_design function
  begin_design()
})

//Click event listener for edit button
editBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  isDesign = false;
  isEdit = true;

  editBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#BA4A00'
  editBtn.style.color = '#17202A'

  designBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
  designBtn.style.color = null

  //Invoke edit_design function
  edit_design()
})



//Function creates new element and then appends it to the parent div
function create_circle_element(x, y){
  let circle = document.createElement('div')

  const circleHeight = 40;
  const circleWidth = 40;

  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  circle.style.height = `${circleHeight}px`;
  circle.style.width = `${circleWidth}px`;
  circle.style.borderRadius = '50%'
  circle.style.textAlign = 'center';
  circle.style.lineHeight = `${circleHeight}px`;
  circle.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  circle.style.left = `${(x - (canvas.offsetLeft + canvasContainer.offsetLeft - window.scrollX)) - (circleWidth/2)}px`;
  circle.style.top = `${(y -(canvas.offsetTop + canvasContainer.offsetTop - window.scrollY)) - (circleHeight/2)}px`

  circle.textContent = `${count}`;
  canvas.append(circle)
  circleArray.push(circle)
  count++
}


//Function responsible for adding circles to the canvas
//Function is invoked when design button is clicked
function begin_design(){
    let mousePosition;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{
    if(isDesign){
      mousePosition = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      }
        create_circle_element(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y)
      }
    })
}


//Function responsible for editing the circles on the canvas i.e moving them around on mousedown/mousemove event
//Function is invoked when edit button is clicked
function edit_design(){
  if(isEdit){
  let mouseDown = false;
  let offset = [];
  let circleClickedOn = [];

//Set mouseDown to false
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
    mouseDown = false
  })

//Loop through the newly created circles and attached 'mousedown' event to each
  circleArray.forEach((circleElement)=>{
    circleElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{

      mouseDown = true;
      offset = [
        circleElement.offsetLeft - event.clientX,
        circleElement.offsetTop - event.clientY
      ]
      circleClickedOn = [circleElement]
    })
  })

//Move circles around
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
    if(mouseDown){
     let mousePosition;

     mousePosition = {
       x: event.clientX,
       y: event.clientY
     }

     circleClickedOn[0].style.left = `${offset[0] + mousePosition.x}px`
     circleClickedOn[0].style.top = `${offset[1] + mousePosition.y}px`
    }
  })
}
}
```

```
***HTML***
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-top">
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="toggle-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-center">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="design-btn">
                <i class='bx bx-pyramid'></i>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" id="edit-btn">
                <i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <div id="canvas"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
***CSS***
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #17202A;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-top{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-top #toggle-btn{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #808B96
}

.sidebar .sidebar-center{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #808B96
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #2e4053
}


.canvas-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2E4053
}

.canvas-container #canvas{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Also, you are adding additional event listeners every time the button is clicked, but you never remove the previous ones.

Comment: Hello I went ahead and added the snippet to the post. Thank you

Comment: @CherryDT, what eventlistener are you speaking of?

Comment: mousedown and mouseup

Comment: I see. Where exactly should they be removed? I cant remove it within the click event for each button because that prevents it from adding the circles.

Comment: When leaving the corresponding modes (desofn/edit). But perhaps it would be easier if they'd be added once, together with the button click listeners, and never be removed, and they should check for the flags you set (like isDesign) to determine whether they should take action or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The issue is you're registering the mouse-down event handler in design mode every time user switches to the design mode.
2. However **you never unregister the mouse-down event handler** upon switching to edit mode.
3. This results in multiple event handler to be registered for canvas click event(mouse-down).
4. So whenever you switch back to the design mode and click upon the canvas, it fires click handler for previously registered listener as well as the newly registered listener.
5. Check the updated snippet

> Comment lines marked with **// Solution :**

```js
//Global variables
let count = 1;
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let canvasContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container');
let designBtn = document.querySelector('#design-btn');
let editBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-btn');
let isDesign = false;
let isEdit = false;
let circleArray = [];
let offset = [];


//Click event listener for design button
designBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  isDesign = true;
  isEdit = false;

  designBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#BA4A00'
  designBtn.style.color = '#17202A'

  editBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
  editBtn.style.color = null

  //Invoke being_design function
  begin_design()
})

//Click event listener for edit button
editBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  isDesign = false;
  isEdit = true;

  editBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#BA4A00'
  editBtn.style.color = '#17202A'

  designBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
  designBtn.style.color = null

  //Invoke edit_design function
  edit_design()
})



//Function creates new element and then appends it to the parent div
function create_circle_element(x, y){
  let circle = document.createElement('div')

  const circleHeight = 40;
  const circleWidth = 40;

  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  circle.style.height = `${circleHeight}px`;
  circle.style.width = `${circleWidth}px`;
  circle.style.borderRadius = '50%'
  circle.style.textAlign = 'center';
  circle.style.lineHeight = `${circleHeight}px`;
  circle.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  circle.style.left = `${(x - (canvas.offsetLeft + canvasContainer.offsetLeft - window.scrollX)) - (circleWidth/2)}px`;
  circle.style.top = `${(y -(canvas.offsetTop + canvasContainer.offsetTop - window.scrollY)) - (circleHeight/2)}px`

  circle.textContent = `${count}`;
  canvas.append(circle)
  circleArray.push(circle)
  count++
}

// Solution : Define a click handler
var designClickHandler = (event)=>{
    if(isDesign){
      mousePosition = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      }
        create_circle_element(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
      }
    }

//Function responsible for adding circles to the canvas
//Function is invoked when design button is clicked
function begin_design(){
    let mousePosition;
    
    // Solution : Register click handler
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', designClickHandler)
}


//Function responsible for editing the circles on the canvas i.e moving them around on mousedown/mousemove event
//Function is invoked when edit button is clicked
function edit_design(){
  if(isEdit){
  
  // Solution : unregister click handler
  canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', designClickHandler)

  
  let mouseDown = false;
  let offset = [];
  let circleClickedOn = [];

//Set mouseDown to false
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
    mouseDown = false
  })

//Loop through the newly created circles and attached 'mousedown' event to each
  circleArray.forEach((circleElement)=>{
    circleElement.addEventListener('mousedown', (event)=>{

      mouseDown = true;
      offset = [
        circleElement.offsetLeft - event.clientX,
        circleElement.offsetTop - event.clientY
      ]
      circleClickedOn = [circleElement]
    })
  })

//Move circles around
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
    if(mouseDown){
     let mousePosition;

     mousePosition = {
       x: event.clientX,
       y: event.clientY
     }

     circleClickedOn[0].style.left = `${offset[0] + mousePosition.x}px`
     circleClickedOn[0].style.top = `${offset[1] + mousePosition.y}px`
    }
  })
}
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  user-select: none;
}


.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #17202A;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-top{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-top #toggle-btn{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #808B96
}

.sidebar .sidebar-center{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #808B96
}
.sidebar .sidebar-center ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #2e4053
}


.canvas-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2E4053
}

.canvas-container #canvas{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hiveport</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-top">
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="toggle-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-center">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="design-btn">
                <i class='bx bx-pyramid'></i>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" id="edit-btn">
                <i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <div id="canvas"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: After 9 hours, the +50 bounty points will be rewarded. Thank you